# I want to use my custom icon.png in my react js app like a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, icons

[image: ****]

Integrate my custom icon.png in my ap like a button

Comment: I think you forgot to show your attempt?

Comment: i didn t try anything because i dont know how

Comment: please follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . we are here to help answer specific questions or help fix broken code, not just do the work for you. there's tutorials or https://www.upwork.com/ for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add something, use `.png` has button. Here is an example:

```
<button id="home_button">click me</button>


#home_button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfed8.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert you png to svg, you can use the library react-icon-base to render you own icons.

```
`<IconBase viewBox="0 0 42 42" height="18" width="18">
    <path
        fillRule="evenodd"
        clipRule="evenodd"
        d="....(your value)"
        fill="currentColor"
    />
 </IconBase>`
```